# Iterar un JSON y acceder a las claves a ciegas. Angular2

Tags: json, angular

Vuelvo desde el principio a Reestructurar toda la pregunta :

Voy a recibir el detalle de un Master/detail del AgGrid, el problema es que no sé cuantos elementos voy a recibir ni cuál es la clave que voy a recibir, ya que cambiarán los elementos y las claves cada x tiempo.

En la imagen 1º, es el resultado que quiero obtener, despliego el Master y se puede ver mockeado que obtengo 4 grupos(En rojo) (que puede variar el número de elementos que voy a recibir.)

Y cada grupo puede tener un número x de elementos.

Recuerdo que todo esto es el detail.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen 2 es lo que de momento estoy consiguiendo a duras penas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos los tengo que sacar sin su conocer su clave  por ejemplo

```
value['name'] value['text']
```

No me vale porque como ya dije, los datos van a venir diferentes cada x tiempo

El problema ya no es conseguir esos datos, que eso a duras penas como se puede ver, ya estoy accediendo a los atributos de los hijos con una serie de objeto.foreach

La estructura del JSON a modo de ejemplo :

```
 "masterdetail": [ {
          "child1": [
            {
            }
          ],
          "child2": [
            {
            }
          ],
         }]
```

Recordando que puede venir 'x' childs y cada child puede venir con 'x' campos.

El problemón me viene cuando quiera MOSTRARLO en el html (por consola no me vale)

Esto se hace con   `this.detailCellRendererParams`

```
template: function(params) {

  --->>>  MIS FOR EACHS.

  return (
          '<div class="aggrid--full-row-container"> ( el contenido )'
         );
      }
    };
  }
```

Yo vengo de PHP Y JSP y siempre he podido intercalar en el foreach una salida del html, pero aquí, si pongo el foreach dentro del return no me deja.

Entonces, y *a modo de resumen*, sacar los datos sin las claves, ya lo estoy sacando poco a poco a duras penas con el console.log , pero el MOSTRARLOS dentro del return no sé como hacerlo porque no me deja poner el foreach dentro del return.

Gracias a todos !!

Comment: ¿Entonces lo que quieres es recorrer el array masterdetail?

Comment: sí, y lo estoy recorriendo, me saca datos como se puede ver, pero dentro de cada uno, sus arrays ya no sé como se recorren.

Comment: Pero masterdetail sólo tiene un elemento, que a su vez parece tener muchos elementos... o puede haber más elementos en el array?

Comment: @PabloLozano masterdetail puede tener un número indefinido de child, child1,2,3,4,5...etc. y cada child un número indefinido de atributos con nombres diferentes, entonces el problema es como accedo a una cantidad que no conozco y lo más importante, como acceso a atributos que no sabré que nombre('clave') voy a recibir

Comment: el obj[key] me saca directamente todo lo que tengo en el masterDetail, quizás si pudiera sacar cada "entro con sus datos, me sería más fácil..."Aunque sigo sin saber como podría acceder a los datos sin usar los identificadores.

Comment: Me parece que el diseño es horrible por el lado de backend... porque no veo la utilidad de mostrar los datos así... ¿Y cómo quieres tenerlos, tras procesarlos?

Comment: más o menos haciendo chapuzas... ya puedo acceder a cada child de forma independiente fuera del return del  template detailGridOptions, el problema es que si lo tengo fuera en un foreach, a ver como lo hago dentro del return porque no me deja hacer un foreach dentro del return ...

Comment: Si añades la estructura que quieres como salida lo mismo podemos echarte una mano...

Comment: @PabloLozano He puesto absolutamente todo de cero, poniendo los cambios, imágenes y todo, espero que ahora se pueda resolver.. gracias

Comment: Creo que será mejor que aclaremos dudas en una sala de chat... he creado una que te debe haber sido notificada ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a la ayuda de Pablo Lozano y JackNavaRow.

Para mostrar en el `detailGridOptions` un Json el cuál no se sabe la cantidad de 
elementos que va a traer y cada elementos no se sabe la clave que va a tener.
La solución es :

```
        const objects = params.data.masterdetail[0];
        const keys = Object.keys(objects);
        let value;
        let content;
        let childKey;
        let result = '<ul>';

        keys.forEach(key => {
          value = objects[key];
          content = value[0];
          console.log('todo el Hijo ', content);
          childKey = Object.keys(content);
          childKey.forEach(childs => {
            console.log('Atributos', childs);
            result = result + '<li><label>' + childs + ':</label>' + content[childs] + '</li>';
          });
          result = result + '</ul>';
        });
        // console.log('template ', params.data.masterdetail);
        return (
          '<div class="aggrid--full-row-container">' + result + '<div ref="eDetailGrid" </div>' + '</div>'
        );
```

Aunque faltaría darle un poco de Css para los estilos, ya muestro los datos. Muchas gracias =)